# What is the relevance of the 'You're So Cool, Brewster!' line in 'Fright Night'?

Tags: dialogue, reception, fright-night

Most people know it, it is a well known line from the cult classic [*Fright Night*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089175/) (1985).

As a non-native English speaker, I can't understand what makes this particular line so relevant and/or important. It seems to be perhaps the most remembered and quoted line from that movie (even the documentary about the movie is called [*You're So Cool, Brewster! The Story of Fright Night*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4621782/) (2016)), but within the context of the movie and the plot development it has very little (if not zero) relevance.

Am I missing something? Is this something more related to the English language than the movie itself? Why did it gain so much relevance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a particularly funny scene because he had just been making up with her after rebuffing her forwardness the night before. She then embarrasses him in front of everyone and then his friend rubs it in with a sarcastic comment. I recalled him talking about how cool he was in a previous scene, but I couldn’t find it.